How to reconstruct UnivswapV3 pool TVL and liquidity via ordered events?
I have been trying to reconstruct the TVL and liquidity of a V3 pool via ordered events : TxIndex > LogIndex. By following the logic in the Graph V3 pool repositories such as this  univ3 graph repo
At least for the liquidity value of the pool ( not the TVL ) it seems simple enough, it needs to be added or subtracted each event that has a liquidity amount value, sequentially.
The problem is that for both TVL and liquidity, amounts end up being negative. I have tracked exactly where the first subtraction to negative happens and it looks like something is affecting the pool and it's not recorded in an event. Would this be because there is an internal transaction happening that modifies the liquidity / TVL values that is not logged ?
Should I just give up on trying to reconstruct TVL / liquidity via events or is there a way to track these other changes that are not visible via other events ?

It's possible to track the evolution both values via events. (Stress on the "evolution" bit, if you only need just the latest state, this answer is more relevant.)
The following events change TVL. The change can be inferred from the amount0 and amount1 fields in the events.

Swap
Mint
Flash
Collect
CollectProtocol

The following events change liquidity. Swap includes the liquidity value after the change, the others include the liquidity delta:

Swap
Mint
Burn

Note that Swap and Mint events change both the TVL and liquidity. From them, Swap is by far the trickiest. While using it for tracking the TVL is relatively simple, and active liquidity after the swap is a field in the Swap event, to track the full changes in liquidity distribution you essentially need to write a v3 swap simulator.

"for the liquidity value of the pool it seems simple enough, it needs to be added or subtracted each event that has a liquidity amount value" - this is not correct, see above.

Generally, the TVL should not change because of other reasons, but there are some edge cases:

anyone can transfer ERC20 tokens to the pool's contract, which means that the TVL computed from the events will be a lower bound from the actual value.
if the pool has rebasing tokens or some other kind of "weird" ERC20 tokens, the pool will not have the correct data because they essentiully break the protocol.

However, liquidity should never change, except due to Swap, Mint, and Burn events.
